# Template specialization static member in different namespace

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, visual-c++, gcc

There is a template class in a namespace

```
namespace N
{
    template <typename T>
    class Foo {
        static const T bar;
    };
}
```

And a specialization in a different namespace:

```
namespace O
{
    typedef N::Foo<int> Baz;

    template<>
    const int Baz::bar = 1;
}
```

This code compiles with gcc (4.9.2) but fails to compile with msvc (v120):

```
error C2888: 'const int N::Foo<int>::bar' : symbol cannot be defined within namespace 'O'
```

If I understand this correctly, the code is not C++11 compliant:

> An explicit specialization shall be declared in a namespace enclosing the
>   specialized template. An explicit specialization whose declarator-id
>   is not qualified shall be declared in the nearest enclosing namespace
>   of the template, or, if the namespace is inline (7.3.1), any namespace
>   from its enclosing namespace set.

Is this a compiler bug or do I misunderstand?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a compiler bug, and [still present in HEAD](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/QAQ02z160nYGdw9G). Please report it. Clang provides a clearer diagnostic:

> error: cannot define or redeclare 'bar' here because namespace 'O'
>   does not enclose namespace 'Foo'
>
> ```
> const int Baz::bar = 1;
>           ~~~~~^
> ```

Comment: GCC bug reported: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=103426